# Swift 5: centerXAnchor won't center my frame in the view

Tags: swift, uikit, nslayoutconstraint, swift5, ios-autolayout

I'm stuck at the *Consolidation IV* challenge from hackingwithswift.com.

Right now I'm trying to create a hangman game. I thought to place placeholder labels based on the length of the answer word. These placeholder labels would be placed inside a frame, which then would be placed in the center of the main view.

Unfortunately, the leading edge of the frame is placed centered. In my opinion, this is not a problem of constraints, but rather a problem of me creating the frame wrong.

My current code is

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var answer: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // MARK: - declare all the labels here
        let letterView = UIView()
        letterView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
        view.addSubview(letterView)

        // MARK: - set constraints to all labels, buttons etc.

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            letterView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            letterView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.centerXAnchor)

        ])

        // MARK: - populate the letterView

        // set the size of the placeholder
        answer = "Atmosphäre"
        let height = 60
        let width = 25
        // var width: Int

        for placeholder in 0..<answer.count {
            // create new label and give it a big font size
            let placeholderLabel = UILabel()
            placeholderLabel.text = "_"
            placeholderLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)

            // calculate frame of this label
            let frame = CGRect(x: placeholder * width, y: height, width: width, height: height)
            placeholderLabel.frame = frame

            // add label to the label view
            letterView.addSubview(placeholderLabel)

        }



    }


}
```

The simulator screen looks just like this:

[image]

I already searched for answers on stackoverflow, but wasn't successful. I think I don't know what I'm exactly looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem, is that the `letterView` has no size, because no width or height constraints are applied to it.

To fix your code make the `letterView` big enough to contain the labels you've added as subviews by adding height and width constraints after the `for` loop:

```
for placeholder in 0..<answer.count {
   ...         
}

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   letterView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(width * answer.count)),
   letterView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(height))
])
```

I'm not sure if you've covered this in your course yet, but a better way to go about this (which would take much less code), is to use a `UIStackView` as your `letterView` instead.

An extra thing to consider:

If you give the `letterView` a background color, you'll see that the labels are actually aligned outside of its bounds:

[image]

That's because you're setting each label's y position to be `height`, when it should probably be zero:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: placeholder * width, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
```

Correcting this places the labels within the bounds of the `letterView`:

[image]